# Print to terminal or commandline with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to print to terminal from a typescript file? When I execute scripts using tsc I'd like to see output in terminal..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a typescript file to print through the CLI , you need to use `ts-node`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

I hope this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can use `npx tsc file.ts`. file.tx is your typescript file

you notice a new compiled file called file.js

so: run this file using `node file.js`

you see output in the terminal

the file.js is just file.ts file compiled into file.js

hope its clear